# I am getting an error in Xcode : "Could not find Developer disk image"

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to install application in my iPhone but right now i'm facing critical problem during installation. It works perfectly in Xcode simulator but when I am testing it on my iPhone it gives me error message like "Could not find developer disk image". I have Xcode version 7.2 and iOS 9.3.1(13E38) version in iPhone. So what I need to do to install the application in iPhone?

Comment: in simple solution update your xcode to 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update Xcode to run your apps on software that new. Xcode 7.2 does not include iOS 9.3.1 beta sdk.

[Xcode download](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Maybe you need to wait for the Xcode's update for iOS9.3.1 that your Xcode could support your iPhone. Commonly I don't update my testing phone to avoid trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Upload Xcode to the latest version as the IOS Updated you need to update Xcode as well, or you can generate an Url for your build and install it on ur phone/pad

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to update the Xcode to it's latest version. But if you don't want to update there is other way to do it is get disk image from any of your other developer friend for iOS 9.3 and install it at the `Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` path just you need to change at `Xcode-beta.app` to your current Xcode app name.

Happy Coding :)